# A phrase for making up excuses?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a phrase or idiom for when someone is making up some tragic story to excuse themselves (such as: "Sorry I didn't show up; my father was diagnosed with cancer".. or "I can't keep our appointment; guess what I lost my job!"). And I got to think of a danish expression; "talking for one's sick auntie"; although that expression usually means doing a lot of talk to achieve some benefit. But my focus was particularly on making up excuses, and I was wondering if there might be a similar expression in english?

Comment: Not a phrase, but this is typically referred to as a sob story

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression I always use in this situation is "The dog ate my homework!"

For example, someone gives a pathetic excuse for something, and the response is an ironic reply of "The dog ate my homework!" usually accompanied by eye-rolling.

Comment: Another doggy did it: A 'shaggy dog story,' a long-winded tale of low substance sometimes used to tire the listener into accepting the story.

Comment: Good, but a shaggy dog story is not necessarily an excuse, it can be any long-winded story.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and your answer is better than my comment, so I upvoted yours and have no other excuse.

Comment: A dog ate your homework, and your excuse :) Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Ah yes, I recall having heard that before. And I believe that's exactly the kind of expression I was looking for. - Thank you very much, both of you. :)

Comment: I'd be pleased to.. is there an "accept" button or something? - I'm completely new to the site.